# How to build a "right to left" linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a chatroom bubble listview, and i meet a problem;
The right bubble layout xml is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="end"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/portrait"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

and the result looks like the picture, why does it go out of the left border

[image]

Comment: You are strongly recommended to use a TextView holding a **compound drawable**, instead of using a `TextView/ImageView pair`. For **better performances**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/portrait"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/portrait"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

         </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: just change `android:layout_width="0dp"` and add `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/portrait"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```